SetAllPalette in Pascal
I have this function which does:
 MyPalette : PaletteType;
 MyPalette.Size:=16;
 // sets some colors
 SetAllPalette(MyPalette);

Reading the Turbo Pascal 5.0 manual it says:

Palette is an untyped parameter. The first byte is the length of the
palette. The next n bytes will replace the current palette colors.
Each color may range from -1 to
15. A value of -1 will not change the previous entry's value.

What I dont get is what happens if you only set 16 or 4 colors in VGA mode? what will the rest of the 256 colors be? Also how come you can only choose amongst 16 colors?

Maybe Turbo Pascal already has a suitable procedure for 256-color VGA modes, but otherwise you could always write your own that first outputs the starting color number to port 0x3c8, and then the red green and blue values to port 0x3c9.

Yeah but what I'm asking is what's the behavior when you set 16 color on VGA mode, because I found it in some old code

vga modes: 320x200x256 colors, but 640x480x16 colors.

This is 320x200x256 tho
